# Implementing Bootstrap 3.0 in MVC4 Razor Grid responsive?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-metro

I am curious to implement Bootstrap css for my project (MVC4).

I have already implemented Metro style.
But it’s not responsive in the phones.  So I thought of Implementing Bootstrap css.  I have downloaded Bootstrap 3.0. 
I don’t see any example that how to implement Bootstrap css in MVC4 Razor webgrid?

Is it possible to achieve responsive Webgrid in MVC4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution to make MVC web grid responsive using bootstrap 3 css. Hope it might be helpful to somebody.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1)').addClass("hidden-xs");
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').addClass("hidden-xs");
$('td:nth-child(4),th:nth-child(4)').addClass("hidden-xs");
$('td:nth-child(5),th:nth-child(5)').addClass("hidden-xs");
$('td:nth-child(6),th:nth-child(6)').addClass("visible-lg");
$('td:nth-child(7),th:nth-child(7)').addClass("hidden-xs");
$('td:nth-child(8),th:nth-child(8)').addClass("hidden-xs");
</script>
```